# The following method did not exist: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am currently creating a basic API using Springboot and postgresql. After writing the application, I get the following error:

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.java:49)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V

The method's class, org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class
    jar:file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor: file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

2021-01-12 16:29:22.405  INFO 22980 --- [           main] c.c.s.SpringbootAwsLambdaApplication     : Starting SpringbootAwsLambdaApplication on Davids-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 22980 (/Users/admin/Desktop/springboot-aws-lambda-real/target/classes started by admin in /Users/admin/Desktop/springboot-aws-lambda-real)
2021-01-12 16:29:22.415  INFO 22980 --- [           main] c.c.s.SpringbootAwsLambdaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-12 16:29:23.595  INFO 22980 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2021-01-12 16:29:23.895  INFO 22980 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 289ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-12 16:29:24.557  WARN 22980 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/dao/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
2021-01-12 16:29:24.586  INFO 22980 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-12 16:29:24.590 ERROR 22980 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 



Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
```

I understand that this is dependency issue as some versions of the components are conflicting with each other. How would I go around fixing the classpath as suggested?

Here is my pom.xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.csunARCS</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-aws-lambda</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-aws-lambda</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
         <wrapper.version>1.0.17.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency> 
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>${wrapper.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <dependencyConvergence />
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>springboot-aws-lambda</finalName>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Remove `spring-jpa` dependency. You are mxing jars from different versions of a framework (in this case spring) never do that as that will lead to weird issues.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!!